# Calculate How Many Overlapping Dates There Are Within Multiple Date Ranges

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, date-range

I need to be able to calculate the number of days when someone was taking at least 1 drug from Class A and 1 drug from Class B.

One of the biggest issues I am encountering is that prescriptions for the same Drug Class may overlap each other and when they are joined to Class B prescriptions I end up double counting days.

For example, between 01/01/21 and 06/30/21, what's the total number of days for each individual where they took a drug from Class A and from Class B

I have fake data below as an example.

TABLE 1

```
| ID | START | END | CLASS |
|:---- |:------| :-----| :-----|
|1234   |12-Feb-21  |19-Feb-21| A
|1234   |20-Feb-21  |22-Feb-21| A
|1243   |13-Mar-21  |23-Mar-21| A
|1234   |21-Apr-21  |1-May-21   |A
|1234   |20-Jun-21  |25-Jun-21  |A
|1234   |11-Jul-21  |16-Jul-21  |A
|4321   |25-Jan-21  |24-Feb-21  |A
|4321   |31-Jan-21  |2-Mar-21   |A
|4321   |28-Feb-21  |30-Mar-21  |A
|4321   |25-Mar-21  |24-Apr-21  |A
|4321   |25-Mar-21  |24-Apr-21  |A
|4321   |25-Apr-21  |25-May-21  |A
|4321   |29-Apr-21  |29-May-21  |A
|4321   |23-May-21  |22-Jun-21  |A
|4321   |26-May-21  |25-Jun-21  |A
|4321   |23-Jun-21  |23-Jul-21  |A
|4321   |23-Jun-21  |23-Jul-21  |A
```

TABLE 2

```
| ID | START | END | CLASS |
|:---- |:------| :-----| :-----|
|1234   |18-Jan-21  |17-Feb-21  |B
|1234   |17-Mar-21  |16-Apr-21  |B
|1234   |14-Apr-21  |14-May-21  |B
|1234   |12-May-21  |11-Jun-21  |B
|1234   |9-Jun-21   |9-Jul-21   |B
|1234   |11-Jul-21  |10-Aug-21  |B
|4321   |25-Jan-21  |24-Feb-21  |B
|4321   |11-Feb-21  |13-Mar-21  |B
|4321   |7-Mar-21   |6-Apr-21   |B
|4321   |4-Apr-21   |4-May-21   |B
|4321   |30-Apr-21  |30-May-21  |B
|4321   |24-May-21  |23-Jun-21  |B
|4321   |20-Jun-21  |20-Jul-21  |B
```

PS - I am working in Oracle SQL Developer

Answer (score 2):

A relatively simple approach is a brute-force approach.  This splits the periods into days for each `class`.  Then joins and aggregates to get the total:

```
with cte1(id, d, endd, class) as (
      select id, startd, endd, class
      from table1
      union all
      select id, d + interval '1' day, endd, class
      from cte1
      where d < endd
     ),
     cte2(id, d, endd, class) as (
      select id, startd, endd, class
      from table2
      union all
      select id, d + interval '1' day, endd, class
      from cte2 -- edit here
      where d < endd
     )
select cte1.id, count(*)
from cte1 join
     cte2
     on cte1.id = cte2.id and cte1.d = cte2.d
group by cte1.id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=69a210fef7f6e7f3b9fa6fe2c19bba52) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: when forming cte2 it incorrectly unions to cte1 and hence produces an incorrect result. the correct result is 36 (from the sample data at dbfiddle)

Comment: I edited the answer as it was just a typo, forgive me

Comment: @PaulMaxwell . . . I also replaced the db<>fiddle.